# Multiple notifications on a tile in metro apps?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs, badge

Am working with tiles and badges in metro apps. Here am able to display one at a time either image or number on a tile , But unable to display both at a time. Can anyone help me how to display image and some-number on a Tile?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Tile]

As MSDN states:

> A notification badge conveys summary or status information concerning and specific to your app. They can be numeric (1-99) ***or*** one of a set of Windows-provided glyphs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh779719.aspx

Note: When you hit limits like this you might consider building a custom image that simply has whatever you want. But then you will realize that rendering an image in WinRT is not possible yet. So you will want to offload to some web server... just helping you think this through.